# Perfect square all 9's

Tags: number-theory

For $9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999,\dots$, except $9$, are the rest of the numbers $9$'s perfect squares? Are there other perfect squares with all $9$'s.

This problem is given for K-12 students, which I have no idea how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you do any special cases?

Comment: 9k is a perfect square if and only if k is a perfect square, so this question is equivalent to asking whether a number that's all 1's is a perfect square, other than 1 itself.

Comment: What are special cases? To me, 9 is the only perfect square among 9, 99, 999,... I'm not sure if it's true.

Comment: How about when the count of 9's is even?  Do you see why these cases are *not* squares?

Comment: To be honest, this is not my field. I can only think I can write those even count numbers like: $10^{2k} -1$, which fails to be a perfect square because suppose yes. Then $10^{2k}$ is a perfect square, which implies we have 2 perfect squares different at most 1 (a contradiction).

Comment: Write $r$ nines as $10^r-1$. The easy solution, i.e. considering the expression modulo 4, has already been given: $10^r \equiv 2^r \pmod{4}$. For $r=1$ we know that $10^r-1$ is really a square. For $r>1$, we have $10^r \equiv 2^r = (2 \cdot 2) \cdot 2^{r-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ and therefore $10^r-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$. But $-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo 4. So that is elementary. If we are allowed to use known "hard" theorems, [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihăilescu's_theorem) says that no perfect square can precede a perfect $r$ power for $r>1$.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Consider these numbers modulo 4.

> **Theorem:**
>
> A number $n^2$ with $n$ an integer satisfies either $n^2\equiv 0(\text{mod}4)$ or $n^2\equiv 1(\text{mod}4)$

*Proof of theorem:*

Case 1: $n\equiv 0$ or $2(\text{mod}4)$.  Then $n^2\equiv 0(\text{mod}4)$

Case 2: $n\equiv 1(\text{mod}4)$.  Then $n^2\equiv 1(\text{mod}4)$

Case 3: $n\equiv 3(\text{mod}4)$.  Then $n^2\equiv 1(\text{mod}4)$

> **Corollary:**
>
> A number which is $2(\text{mod}4)$ or $3(\text{mod}4)$ cannot be a perfect square.

Now, look at $9\dots 99(\text{mod}4)$

A number modulo 4 is congruent to the final two digits modulo 4, and $99(\text{mod}4)$ is congruent to $3$, therefore is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 11):

There are not a lot of tools at K-12 for this problem, so use the simplest one: take the last several digits.  The last digit is a square, so look at the final two digits.

> There is no perfect square ending in 99

because

> any perfect square leaves a remainder of 0 or 1 when divided by 4

Answer (score 2):

All integers can be written as $10n\pm k$, where $0\le k\le5$. Squaring, we have $100n^2\pm20nk+k^2$, which for $0\le k^2<10\iff0\le k\le3$ has an even tens digit, and the remaining two options do not produce a $9$ at the last position. $($In general, no “repdigit” in base $10$ can ever be a square$)$.